# Does the Monk retain his AC Bonus if he loses his Dex bonus to AC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor-class

Does a monk retain the AC bonus from the [**AC Bonus (Ex)**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-AC-Bonus-Ex-) class feature if he loses his Dex bonus to AC? It says he retains it if he's flat-footed, but there are other ways to lose your Dex bonus to AC.

Answer (score 16):

**Yes**, he keeps his monk AC bonus if he loses his Dexterity bonus to AC. From the monk's AC bonus class feature:

> He loses these bonuses when he is immobilized or helpless, when he wears any armor, when he carries a shield, or when he carries a medium or heavy load.

These are the only conditions that cause a monk to lose their AC bonus. If he does not meet any of these conditions, he retains his Wisdom bonus to AC, and the 1/4-monk-level AC bonus, unless another effect specifically calls it out.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes.**

This seems like it's answered by a careful reading of the rule.

The [monk AC bonus power says](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk):

> These bonuses to AC apply even against touch attacks or when the monk is flat-footed. He loses these bonuses when he is immobilized or helpless, when he wears any armor, when he carries a shield, or when he carries a medium or heavy load.

So it depends what is causing him to lose his DEX bonus to AC.  Is it being immobilized or helpless? Then yes, he loses it. If it's a touch attack or he's flat-footed, no.

But what about other conditions, like being blinded or cowering or pinned or stunned? Is the first sentence listing "times when they keep it" comprehensive or is the second sentence listing "times when they lose it" comprehensive?

The latter, and the monk retains the bonus in the unlisted conditions.

Why? Logically, there's a lot of cases where you get the bonus, so the first sentence is clearly not comprehensive, whereas there's no real reason to have the first part of the second sentence (immobilized or helpless) if any other condition that usually deprives AC bonus still works on them - it would be redundant.